# Deploying django project on a 2019 windows server virtual machine (offline)

Tags: python, django, apache, nginx, deployment

I've been working on a Django project for a while, and after completing it, I want to deploy it so my colleagues can work with it. I have a virtual machine (Windows Server 2019) that doesn't have internet connection. I copied my Django project there, but the first problem I faced was with the Python packages. Since my project has its own virtual environment, I assumed that by copying the project, everything would work. However, I had to reinstall all the packages offline using the wheel files. This has made me question the purpose of the virtual environment.

I also intend to deploy it using an Apache server.

- When deploying a Django project with Apache, I need the mod_wsgi package. However, when I tried installing it, I encountered this error, even though I have already installed Visual Studio C++ Build Tools 14 :

```
building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mod_wsgi
  Running setup.py clean for mod_wsgi
Failed to build mod_wsgi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mod_wsgi, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

- I have also tried deploying it with Nginx, but I encountered this error.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBj8m.png)

**Seeking guidance on the optimal method to deploy my website (and potentially multiple sites) on a VM without internet access. Your assistance is highly valued, and thank you in advance for any help.**